# SQL Server compact- Query that return 2 constant columns even if query didn't return data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-compact

Please look at the following simple query:

```
Select CustomerID
From Customers c  
Where  c.CustomerId = "1234"
```

I want to write similar query that does the following:

Always return 2 columns with constant string instead of CustomerID in this structure:

If value was found then return 2 columns:
Found Value in DB, CustomerId

Else return:
Didn't found value in DB, CustomerId

How can I do that? Especially in Microsoft compact SQL server limited syntax...

Comment: With "CustomerId" do you mean you want the string `'CustomerId'`be returned or the value `1234`?

Comment: Customer Id the string

Comment: Instead of trying to find some convoluted way to solve this in the query (I was going to write a `CASE WHEN EXISTS` clause, but somehow I doubt it will work in Compact), why not just let your application handle this output depending on what it gets back? Or maybe you should consider using SQL Server Express or SQL Server LocalDB instead of continuing to use Compact in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Derived tables and Case statements are supported in SQL CE, so you can use this script

```
Select 
case 
when s.custs = 0 then 'Didnt found value in DB'
else 'found value in DB'
end
,'customer id'
from 
(select COUNT(*) as 'custs' from Customers c Where  c.CustomerId = 1234) s
```

for [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173372%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) check what can and what cannot be used in SQL CE

Answer (score -1):

I don't think the `@@RowCount` is available in SQL CE, so this will be using `COUNT` function.

```
Declare @cnt INT=0

Select @cnt=CustomerID
From Customers c  
Where  c.CustomerId = "1234"

If @cnt = 0

Select  "Didn't Found value in DB"
,"customerid"

If @cnt<>0

Select  "Found value in DB" ,"customerid"
```

Comment: Excuse me, but I couldn't find the the `count()` function in your code.